# acts_as_taggable_on url friendly tag names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

Is there a way to make the tag name on acts_as_taggable_on to be URL friendly?

For example, at the moment I have 'tags/foo' and 'tags/bar' working great. However when I add spaces to the name such as 'rabbits foot' the url is 'tags/rabbits%20foot'. I'd like to replace that %20 with a dash.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that stackoverflow actually uses a very similar or identical way of doing tags to what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this
https://github.com/arturaz/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

It has a way to change the multiple words into a slug (e.g. rabbits foot into rabbits-foot), there's also manual non plugin ways to do this as well (it looks somewhat outdated).

Comment: Thanks ahuang. I think that's exactly what I need, however I'm not sure that plugin is Rails 3 compatible. I'm currently using https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on and it works fine except for the lack of a slugizer. Any ideas how to implement this manually?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to kind of cheat and use the id+tag.name just to get passed this hump for now. Will revisit when I have more time.